# Building a website in Sharepoint, but my control panel disappears

Tags: sharepoint-2013

At the moment i'm building a website in sharepoint, but everytime i open the main page of the website in my browser the control panel on the left upperside of the screen is missing. I have no idea why?

To clarify: In this tutorial you can see the browse/page/site control screen, in which they make nearly all the simple changes to the website. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJlwCNXMCBo (edit: Forgot the link of the tutorial)

I literally have no idea why i cant use this, does anyone have any clue?

Edit: My mainpage looks like this:

http://s30.postimg.org/6a5mkzoip/Screenshot_main_page.png

Comment: check your master page and its css

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to give the link of your tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull down the menu with the gear icon beside your name.  Click on "Show Ribbon".

Your master page is hiding it through javascript.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var suitebar = $("#suiteBar");
              if(suitebar.length<1)
                 $("#s4-ribbonrow").css('display','none');
        </script>
```

If you change the master page to $("#s4-ribbonrow").css('display','block');

You should see the ribbon.

Comment: This doesn't work, because i can't see my name either.

Comment: TNX! This was the problem! Had some trouble finding the right spot though. But it worked finally!